# remover os valores repetidos

Tags: javascript, html

Se ele digitar 1, tenho que verificar se na tabela não há nenhum valor 1 que já foi digitado, se existir o valor repetido, remove o valor 1 e mantém o outro intacto. Assim pra outras valores.

**HTML**

```
        <table>
            <tr>
                 <td><input type="text" name="notapergunta2_1" placeholder="Alfa"/> Alfa</td>
                 <td><input type="text" name="notapergunta2_2" placeholder="Chub"/> Chub</td>
                 <td><input type="text" name="notapergunta2_3" placeholder="Met "/> Met </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td><input type="text" name="notapergunta2_4" placeholder="A"/> A</td>
                 <td><input type="text" name="notapergunta2_5" placeholder="G"/> G</td>
                 <td><input type="text" name="notapergunta2_6" placeholder="N"/> N</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td><input type="text" name="notapergunta2_7" placeholder="ASS"/> ASS</td>
                 <td><input type="text" name="notapergunta2_8" placeholder="Hdi"/> Hdi</td>
                 <td><input type="text" name="notapergunta2_9" placeholder="Porto"/> Porto </td>
             </tr>
        </table>
```

**meu javascript:**

```
array = []
for(var i = 0; i<9;i++){
    var numeroDaPergunta = i+1;

    $("[name='notapergunta2_"+numeroDaPergunta+"']").on("change",function(){
        var verificaValorDigitado = $(this).val();

        if(verificaValorDigitado > 3 || verificaValorDigitado <= 0){
            alert("Valor Digitado : "+verificaValorDigitado+"\nDigite Números de 1 a 3");
            $(this).val("");
        } else {
            array.push($(this).val());
            for(var j = 0; j<array.length; j++){
                if(verificaValorDigitado == array[j]){
                    alert("Valor Repetido");
                    $(this).val("");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Não estou conseguindo achar uma solução, poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Que valores repetidos você quer remover? Poderia detalhar melhor a pergunta?

Comment: se ele digitar 1, tenho que verificar se na tabela não há nenhum valor 1 que já foi digitado, se existir o valor repetido, remove o valor 1 e mantem o outro intacto. assim pra outras valores.

Comment: é uma lista de repetidos para cada field ou para todos fields?

Comment: todos os inputs de text estão vazios, se eu digitar 1 eu devo verificar em todos os inputs de text da tabela se existe esse valor, se existir, eu devo remover esse último valor repetido e manter o outro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nessa parte aqui você está adicionando no array o valor atual e depois percorre o **mesmo** array procurando por valores **repetidos**, dessa forma ele **SEMPRE** vai achar porque você está adicionando **ANTES**.

```
array.push($(this).val());
for(var j = 0; j<array.length; j++){
    if(verificaValorDigitado == array[j]){
        alert("Valor Repetido");
        $(this).val("");
        return false;
    }
}
```

É só inverter:

```
for(var j = 0; j<array.length; j++){
    if(verificaValorDigitado == array[j]){
        alert("Valor Repetido");
        $(this).val("");
        return false;
    }
}
array.push($(this).val());
```

Para evitar o problema de digitar o mesmo valor no mesmo campo, basta criar um evento de `onfocus` que vai salvar o valor original do campo antes dele alterar. Faça assim:

```
var valorAnterior; /* variavel global */
$("[name='notapergunta2_"+numeroDaPergunta+"']").on("focus",function(){
    valorAnterior = $(this).val();
}
```

E no seu método de `onchange`, precisa remover seu valor antigo:

```
var index = array.indexOf(valorAnterior);
if (index > -1) {
    array.splice(index, 1); // remove
}
// ... procura repetido
```

Comment: deu certo, mas tem um problema: se eu apagar o input de texto que já está preenchido (digamos que no input tenha valor=1) e tirar ela do foco, ela adiciona na array o valor. se eu apagar (valor=1) neste mesmo input esse valor que acabei de preencher e colocar esse mesmo valor (valor=1) apagado em outra posição do input, ela vai falar que o valor está repetido.

Comment: @jerry Atualizei minha resposta com uma sugestão desse problema ;)

Comment: obrigado, funcionou. só mais uma addendo, só colocar dentro do evento onfocus a condição:  if($(this).val() !=""){valorAnterior = $(this).val();}

Answer (score 1):

Não é mais prático utilizar o método indexOf do que percorer um FOR?

```
var valor = document.querySelector('ELEMENTO_A_SER_CAPTURADO').value;
if (array.indexOf(valor) < 0) 
    array.push(valor);
else 
    alert('valor duplicado');
```

Tem um exemplo funcionando neste link aqui: [exemplo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbzNoP)